# H is a subgroup of G and G' is a subgroup of H. Prove H is normal in G.

Tags: group-theory

> Question:
> Let G be a group and let G' be the subgroup of G generated by the set $S=\left \{ x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \mid x,y \in G \right \}$

$\space$

> Prove that G' is normal in G.
>
> Solved

$\space$

> Prove that G/G' is abelian.
>
> Solved

$\space$

> Prove that if H is a subgroup of G and G' is a subgroup of H, then H is a normal subgroup of G.

I cannot even begin to start on this question.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: The answer you accepted redoes the computations in the first two parts. The other answer should you how the last part follows from the preceding two.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: let $h \in H$. Then you have

$g^{-1}hg = h(h^{-1}g^{-1}hg)$

This is in $H$ because...

**Edit:** (Elaboration for OP) To show that $H \triangleleft G$, it suffices to show that for every $h \in H$, $g^{-1}hg \in H$ for all $g \in G$. What's been shown is that $g^{-1} hg$ can be written as a product of two things in $H$. They are $h$ and $h^{-1}g^{-1}hg \in G' \leq H$. Since $H$ is a subgroup, it follows $g^{-1}hg \in H$.

Comment: What an odd result (to me). It feels like something that should be somewhat deep (akin to $G/N$ abelian iff $N$ contains the commutator subgroup), but it can be proved with basically a dash of "algebraic nonsense."

Comment: I cannot follow it. Everything in the bracket are elements of G.

Comment: Excuse the pointless comment, but: sweet!

Comment: @pjs36 the other answer gives a sense of "why" it's true, but this gives a very direct argument showing that it is. Tradeoffs

Answer (score 7):

By the Correspondence Theorem, you know that $H/G'$ is a subgroup of the quotient group $G/G'$ and it is normal since $G/G'$ is abelian. This gives you that $H$ is normal in G:

> **Correspondence Theorem**
>   If $N$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$, then there is a bijection from the set of all subgroup $A\leq G$ containing $N$ onto the set of all subgroups of the quotient $G/N$. Moreover this bijection respects inclusion, index and normality.